# c# installer without any build-tools

Tags: c#, wpf, installation, windows-installer, azure-pipelines

Is there a Installer-Tool that does require any tool to be installed?
I do not have admin privileges on my build-agent (vsts hosted agent) but still want a normal installer.

I am currently using ClickOnce but that needs so many workarounds that I don't really like it.

I know of Installers like WIX or VS Setup Projects but those don't work without WIX Toolkit or Visual Studio.

I hope anyone has an idea or I will have to do it manually.

Comment: Most of my applications are effectively file copy installed. If you have .net framework on the target you can just copy all the stuff out your bin/release into a folder on their machine and they can run it. I'm a bit confused why you feel visual studio requirement is a problem. You don't need that on a client you install to

Comment: For Hosted agent, both VS and wix are installed (for Hosted VS2017, please refer https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md; for Hosted agent, please refer https://github.com/adventworks/hosted-pool-images/blob/2017.10.02/vs2015-on-windows-2012r2/image.md), so you can build with Hosted agent without any installations.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows#squirrel-its-like-clickonce-but-works). It's an open-source (free) installation and update framework for Windows desktop apps.

[Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/) is another solution for application packaging and deployment on Windows.

Comment: Seems interesting. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

WiX can be pulled into a build server without requiring admin privs.  It has a nuget package just for this purpose.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WiX/

That will require you to not run MSI validation though so be careful.

Also note that WiX does not need VS.  VS Setup does though.